# gunzip partials read from read-stream

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream, gzip

I use `Node.JS` to fetch files from my `S3` bucket.
The files over there are `gzipped` (`gz`).

I know that the contents of each file is composed by lines, where each line is a `JSON` of some record that failed to be put on `Kinesis`.

Each file consists of ~12K such records. and I would like to be able to process the records while the file is being downloaded.

If the file **was not** `gzipped`, that could be easily done using `streams` and `readline` module.
So, the only thing that stopping me from doing this is the `gunzip` process which, to my knowledge, needs to be executed on the whole file.

Is there any way of `gunzipping` a partial of a file?

Thanks.

---

### EDIT 1: (bad example)

Trying what @Mark Adler suggested:

```
  const fileStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
  const lineReader = readline.createInterface({input: fileStream});

  lineReader.on('line', line => {
    const gunzipped = zlib.gunzipSync(line);
    console.log(gunzipped);
  })
```

I get the following error:

> Error: incorrect header check
>       at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:363:17)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. node.js has a [complete interface to zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html), which allows you to decompress as much of a gzip file at a time as you like.

Comment: Could you share an example of how to do such thing? the webpage is undocumented.

Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up @Mark, I have posted a more detailed answer with a working example.

Answer (score 0):

### A working example that solves the above problem

The following solves the problem in the above code:

```
  const fileStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(zlib.createGunzip());
  const lineReader = readline.createInterface({input: fileStream});

  lineReader.on('line', gunzippedLine => {
    console.log(gunzippedLine);
  })
```